# Jquery radio buttonset() not styling in asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I'm simply trying to get a RadioButtonList to work with Jquery buttonset() styling in ASP.Net, 2010 C#.

When I use the code below, the radio buttons do turn into jquery buttons, but with a white background and no font change.  The buttons can be clicked and the values are correct, but appearance of the button stays white with no visual change whatsoever (the UI I'm attempting to use is 'Flick').  Consequently, it isn't possible to tell which button you have clicked.  I've done some testing with a div and a standard set of HTML radio buttons, and they act the same way in ASP.net.  However, when I use the div and standard buttons in a simple HTML page, they are styled correctly with color changes etc.

I'm guessing this problem is caused by ASP.Net loading the RadioButtonList as an input/label/span combination, but if that were the case, it seems that everyone using ASP.Net should be experiencing it.

Any ideas or help would be great appreciated.
Thanks!

```
$(function () {
       $("#<%= audioRadioList.ClientID %>").buttonset();
});

<asp:RadioButtonList ID="audioRadioList" runat="server" CssClass="radioButtons">
<%--  These audio list items are loaded in the code behind on page load --%>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Comment: Could you post the HTML this generates.

Answer (score 0):

If you could post the generated HTML that would be a bug plus...

The following may work

```
$(function () {
       $("input[id*=audioRadioList]").buttonset();
});
```

or

```
$(function () {
       $("input.radioButtons").buttonset();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for those comments!  I think I narrowed the issue down to .net using various html objects (like <TD> and <SPAN> to build radio buttons.  Each of these items had to have the background set to 'transparent' in the CSS.  This seems to have resolved the issue.  Thanks for the response!